# INSERT or UPDATE ON DUPLICATE KEY with SQLAlchemy ORM

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, orm

I'm looking for a function in MYSQLAlchemy's ORM to make a statement for all rows in dataset to load in DDBB at once with insert or update un duplicate key, but only found to execute row by row.

Actually I'm using the following code:

```py
for orm_object in orm_mapped_object:
    session.merge(orm_object )

session.commit()
```

I'm looking for something like this (pseudocode):

```py
session.insert_or_update_all_data(orm_mapped_object)
session.commit()
```

Note: `orm_mapped_object` is a list of mapped objects

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for [on_duplicate_key_update](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/dialects/mysql.html#insert-on-duplicate-key-update-upsert)

Comment: yes, im looking for this but for all dataset. If I'm not wrong, this doc provides you to update row by row. so I need something to update all at once.