# Sqlalchemy Insert or update (Upsert) using orm session

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, orm

I'm trying to do upsert using sqlalchemy
I know there's no such thing as upsert in sql
but sqlalchemy provides this
https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/dialects/mysql.html#insert-on-duplicate-key-update-upsert

now the same thing I'm trying to perform with sqlalchemy orm session

here's my code

```py
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
Session = sessionmaker(engine)
with Session() as session:
  """Here upsert functionality"""
  session.insert_or_update(company)
  session.commit()
```

[Now merge might be an option considering some other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74208312/insert-or-update-on-duplicate-key-with-sqlalchemy-orm)

```py
session.merge(company)
```

I haven't tried it yet as I'm also looking for multiple records

EDIT: session.merge(company) works fine for me as I only need to check for primary key and not other unique values

Session.merge() examines the primary key attributes of the source instance, and attempts to reconcile it with an instance of the same primary key in the session. If not found locally, it attempts to load the object from the database based on primary key, and if none can be located, creates a new instance. The state of each attribute on the source instance is then copied to the target instance. The resulting target instance is then returned by the method; the original source instance is left unmodified, and un-associated with the Session if not already.

This what [documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Session.merge) says

So now if anyone know how to perform same thing for multiple objects that would be really helpful

Thanks :)